# Erro de sintaxe no MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, syntax-error

Eu estava criando uma tabela no MySQL e apareceu esse erro, neste código:

```
USE cadastro;
CREATE TABLE países(
    cod_país INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    nome_país VARCHAR (30),
    PRIMARY KEY cod_país
    );
```

> 1 erros foram encontrados durante análise.
>
> A closing bracket was expected. (near ")" at position 124)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Está faltando parênteses na linha do `PRIMARY KEY`:

```
CREATE TABLE países (
    cod_país INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    nome_país VARCHAR(30),
    PRIMARY KEY (cod_país)
);
```

Veja [funcionando no **SQLFiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/383a44). [Também coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura.](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/SQL/Create/MySQLIndex.sql)

[Documentação](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-table.html).

Answer (score -2):

Coloque assim e veja se consegue.

```
USE cadastro;
CREATE TABLE países(
    cod_pais INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    nome_país VARCHAR (30),
    PRIMARY KEY (cod_pais)
    );
```

Answer (score -3):

Tire os acentos dos "is" na palavra país. Todos as palavras "**país**" estão escritas com acento agudo no í.

Comment: E por que isso é um erro?